# unsigned xcarchive aps environment missing

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, xcode11, codesign, xcarchive

I want to share unsigned xcarchive. To make unsigned xcarchive. I set Provisional profile and Signing Certificate as None.
I have crated Xcarchive with below commands one by one.

```
xcodebuild -scheme xxxx -workspace xxx.xcworkspace -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath "/Users/exxx/Desktop/PROD/xxx.xcarchive" CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS=/Users/exxx/Desktop/PROD/Cert/entitlements.plist CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

& without passing CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS

```
xcodebuild -scheme xxxx -workspace xxx.xcworkspace -configuration Release clean archive -archivePath "/Users/exxx/Desktop/PROD/xxx.xcarchive" CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO CODE_SIGNING_ALLOWED=NO
```

when I upload that archive with Organizer then at final check it shows Entitlement summary where 'aps-environemt' key always missing. I have attached screen shot for reference. Both builds having same issue.

I also tried the same exported archive to **codesign** with entitlement but that also don't work. (With below command)

```
codesign --entitlements  /Users/xxx/Desktop/PROD/Cert/xxx.entitlements -f -s xxx /Users/xxx/Desktop/PROD/xxx.xcarchive
```

When My upload completed then getting an email from apple as,

Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add APS entitlement to your xcarchive you should `sign` your `.app` file with `entitlements.plist` that has `aps-environment` key (and other needed keys) e.g.:

**entitlements.plist**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Next sign embedded frameworks and your app file with the entitlements:

```sh
$ codesign -f -s "<codesiging identity>" -v /foo.xcarchive/Products/Application/foo.app/Frameworks/*
$ codesign -f -s "<codesiging identity>" --entitlements /pathToEntitlements/entitlements.plist /foo.xcarchive/Products/Application/foo.app
```

To get available codesign identities run next command:

```sh
security find-identity -vp codesigning
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, the push notification it's working!! Thank you!!!